# So webmatrix cannot connect to a port different than default one?

Tags: mysql, port, webmatrix-2

I'm trying to connect to `localhost`:`45000` (it is a [tunnel to my pagodabox MySQL](http://help.pagodabox.com/customer/portal/articles/175427))

---

[image: C:\Windows\system32\conhost.exe]

---

But in webmatrix I get this error:

---

[image: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft WebMatrix\WebMatrix.exe]

```
  Call to GetHostEntry failed after 00:00:00 while querying for hostname 'localhost:45000': SocketErrorCode=HostNotFound, ErrorCode=11001, NativeErrorCode=11001.

  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. ---> System.Exception: Call to GetHostEntry failed after 00:00:00 while querying for hostname 'localhost:45000': SocketErrorCode=HostNotFound, ErrorCode=11001, NativeErrorCode=11001. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known
     at System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name)
     at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
     at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress)
     at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetDnsHostEntry(String hostname)
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetDnsHostEntry(String hostname)
     at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetHostEntry(String hostname)
     at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStreamFromHost(String pipeName, String hostName, UInt32 timeout)
     at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStream(UInt32 timeout)
     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
     at Microsoft.WebMatrix.DatabaseManager.MySqlDatabase.MySqlDatabaseProvider.TestConnection(String connectionString)
     at Microsoft.WebMatrix.DatabaseManager.IisDbManagerModuleService.TestConnection(DatabaseConnection databaseConnection, String configPathState)
     at Microsoft.WebMatrix.DatabaseManager.Client.ClientConnection.Test(ManagementConfigurationPath configPath)
     at Microsoft.WebMatrix.DatabaseManager.Client.DatabaseHierarchyInfo.EnsureLoaded()
```

---

Is it that webmatrix can't handle the 45000 port? (It works otherwise (in MySQL-WorkBench).)

Comment: PS: I've also tried `127.0.0.1:45000`